# Magento 2 resources not loading error 404

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have installed a new copy of Magento Community edition 2... Everything passed and process finished smoothly but the site is not loading properly, non of the resources (js, css, images) so it takes a long time to load and then just get a white page with text.

I am using Apache 2.4, MYSQL 5.6, cPanel/WHM, PHP 5.5

I've looked at other answers on Stack and non are relevant, but it does look like it's a common problem with re writing.. as far as I know rewriting works fines, there are other sites on the server functioning great.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the files in pub\static folder ?

Comment: Yes, although some of the files look like symlinks and when you click them it says file not found

Comment: View page source and check if CSS path going to 404 or not

Comment: i've same problem as well and yes CSS files paths are going to 404.